# The difference between "…to {get, arrive, reach, come} here on time."

Tags: difference, exam-questions, transitivity

This is a B2 question taken from an old English test paper. The student has an original sentence and is given a new word which they must use to create a new sentence–using between two and five words–without changing the meaning of the original.

> There's no chance of Jenny getting here on time
> **POSSIBLE**
> It won't be _______________ here on time.

A private student of mine who's Italian,  wrote

> It won't be **POSSIBLE for Jenny to come** here on time.

My book says the solution above earns the candidate one point, in order to earn two full points the correct answer must be:

> *It won't be*  | possible for | Jenny to GET/ARRIVE/REACH *here on time*.

I'm not disputing that the book's solutions are correct, I disagree that "come" isn't included among the options.

With the preposition "to", *come* and *get* both work

1. I COME to work on time. (YES)
   I GET to work on time. (YES)
   I ARRIVE / REACH to work on time. (NO)

The verb *arrive* can be used in conjunction with the preposition "at":

2. I ARRIVED at the airport on time (Yes)
   I CAME / GOT / REACHED at the airport on time (NO)

When there is no preposition, all of the verbs below are acceptable.

3. I usually COME home on time. (YES)
   I usually GET/ARRIVE/REACH home on time. (YES)

Why does [Cambridge](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/), the ESOL examining centre, consider "come here on time" incorrect in this instance? Does the meaning change?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Usage: Come vs Go](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116158/9161) An answer there points out that it is often the speaker's perspective that controls which word is preferred rather than the direction something or someone travels. The passive nature of the sentence makes it more difficult to decide what perspective to take (I think) so we choose something more neutral like "arrive". "I won't be able to get to your house on time." "Jenny called to let us know she can't come here on time." "It is impossible for Jenny to arrive on time."

Comment: How many points does *...be here on time* get?

Comment: @EllieK the full correct answer gets 2 points. The part where it says | **POSSIBLE FOR** | gets the first mark. | **Jenny to get/arrive/reach** | gets the second mark. The "here on time" is already included in the transformation sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  - So, *It won't be possible for Jenny to be here on time,* gets 0 points.  Maybe something was overlooked.  Probably fear of the double *be*.

Comment: I do think EllieK has a point though that "be" is a perfectly acceptable addition to get/arrive/reach with the limited context that is given. Although I suppose if the book assumes that the student taking the test was taught in a particular way, it is reasonable to limit the possible words there to get the additional point.

Comment: @ColleenV  Oh, I see: ... **for Jenny to be** *here on time*. Well, neither is that included among the possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see *coming* to a place as referring to the action of travelling there, while what happens 'on time' (or not) is the *arrival* there.

*I come to work on time* isn't ungrammatical, but I find *I get to work on time* or *I arrive at work on time* much more natural utterances.

Comment: How about *I am **at** work on time*?

Comment: @EllieK - Yes, that's possible too.

Answer (score 3):

**COME and GO work differently semantically** than  GET/ARRIVE/REACH, and I am not taking the prepositions into account here.

Those two terms involve issues of directionality and speaker location that get, arrive and reach do not.

I will only go into one example, as it can be complicated:

**My boss is at work** or **in her mind is thinking as if she were at that location**.
We're talking on the phone.
My boss says: Can you please come to work on time tomorrow?
Answer: Yes, I can come to work on time tomorrow.

The Cambridge ESOL probably was taking the idea of location and speakers into consideration as that is the only feature that separates *come* usage from get/arrive/reach usage.

Comment: What's the difference if my boss asks *Can you please arrive at work on time tomorrow?* OR *Can you please get to work on time*…? Why would "come here on time" be less natural/idiomatic? I get that the speaker refers to the location as if she were there but why is that different from using "arrive" or "get"? (I'd avoid *reach work* in this instance)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is not about being idiomatic. It's completely idiomatic. However, come means the person asking is at the place or is at the place in her head. That is the difference. "Are you coming home early tomorrow?" you ask your child. You are at home when you say it. For general statements like: I always arrive on time. [wherever], you wouldn't use the verb come. come/go have directionality features that the other do not.

Comment: OK "come" isn't interchangeable with "arrive/get/reach".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Right, and it's due to the location of the speaker and/or interlocutor.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It is interchangeable only in some situations. Not all.